# SQL Statement to Report the number of direct reports of each person who has someone reporting to him or her

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to learn and teach myself sqldeveloper and sql in general but I am stumped at how to write the sql statement that will answer the query " Report the number of direct reports of each person who has someone reporting to him or her."

I had this originally:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEENUMBER, COUNT(EMPLOYEES.REPORTSTO) FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

but that's not giving me a result. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. The only table that is involved I believe, is the "EMPLOYEES" table.

The columns of the employees table are: EMPLOYEENUMBER, LASTNAME, LASTNAME, EXTENTION, EMAIL, OFFICECODE, REPORTSTO, JOBTITLE.

Comment: Have a look at [GROUP BY](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)

Comment: Not giving you a result? I guess it is giving you an error about aggregate functions and GROUP BY right?

Comment: yes that this the error that I was getting.

Comment: In future **post the error**. 'not giving me a result' is useless information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `REPORTSTO` is a `FORIEGN KEY` referencing to back to an `EMPLOYEENUMBER`; i.e. your table (possibly with different data types) has a structure something like:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
  EMPLOYEENUMBER INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRSTNAME      VARCHAR2(50),
  LASTNAME       VARCHAR2(50),
  EXTENTION      VARCHAR2(4),
  EMAIL          VARCHAR2(50),
  OFFICECODE     INT,
  REPORTSTO      INT REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEENUMBER),
  JOBTITLE       VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Then you can `GROUP BY` on the `REPORTSTO` column:

```
SELECT REPORTSTO AS EMPLOYEENUMBER,
       COUNT( 1 ) AS number_reporting_to
FROM   EMPLOYEES
WHERE  REPORTSTO IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY REPORTSTO;
```